# SQL server authentication is grayed out when connecting to integration services

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Why SQL server authentication is only available for connecting to Database Engine but grayed out for rest of all services, AS, RS and IS?

I am on SQL Server 2012.

How can I enable the sa login to AS, RS and IS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Analysis](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/f1-help/connect-to-server-analysis-services) and [Integration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/f1-help/connect-to-server-integration-services) services only use Windows Authentication. [SQL Server Reporting Services](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/f1-help/connect-to-server-reporting-services) would require different configuration to handle different authentication. More detail can be found by clicking on the service links. As such, sa is a SQL Server authentication and cannot be used for logging into those services.